# How can i map more than one user as manager in ldap attribute manager?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, ldap-query, python-ldap

I have doubt in LDAP user manager mapping. Is that possible to have multiple manager for a single user in LDAP. I have one user details of ldap, it contains only one manager mapping with attribute "manager" as shown below.

version: 1
dn: CN=sangeeth,OU=User,DC=domain,DC=com
objectClass: user
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
c: IN
cn: sangeeth
manager: CN=kumar,OU=User,DC=domain,DC=com

Here "CN=kumar,OU=User,DC=domain,DC=com" is the manager of user "CN=sangeeth,OU=User,DC=domain,DC=com". How can i map more than one manager for user sangeeth in LDAP ? . Please let me know if any clarifications required.

If it is possible to add more than one manager for a user, then how can i query a data from LDAP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can not. The manager attribute is marked as:
[Is-Single-Valued   True](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676859(v=vs.85).aspx)

You could,, if you are knowledgable, add a new attribute (like mymanager) that is multi-valued. That would require modioficaiton of the Microsoft Active Directory Schema and it is tricky and not a reversable process.

-jim